# React routing using react-router-dom v.6 doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm trying to create routing for my react.js app by using react-router v.6.
I already tried to do changes for the v.6 but for some reason my app didn't show anything, can anyone help me ?

So Navigation.js file is for Routing, Header.js filled with button for changing route and App.js is used to display them.

App.js:

```
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Outlet/>
    </div>
```

Header.js:

```
<>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/Productlist">Product</Link>
  <Link to="/Contact">Contact Us</Link>
</>
```

Navigation.js:

```
<>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}>
            <Route exact path="ProductList" element={<Product/>}/>
            <Route exact path="ContactUs" element={<Contact/>}/>
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but first you can start by replacing your Navigation.js  by :

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path="ProductList" element={<Product/>}/>
    <Route path="ContactUs" element={<Contact/>}/>
</Routes>
```

In this case you don't need nested routes.

Then, I don't think it's a good idea to use capitalize letter in path.